# Find max() in an instance of a class

Tags: python, max, instance

I am very new to python and programming for that matter. I am just messing around with writing code without following any tutorials (only way i learn) but i am stuck here.

```
class Cars:
def __init__(self, name, speed, seats, mpg, price):
    self.name = name
    self.speed = speed
    self.seats = seats
    self.mpg = mpg
    self.price = price

def car_details(self):
    print("Car Name - ", self.name)
    print("Max Speed - ", self.speed)
    print("Max Persons seated - ", self.seats)
    print("Miles Per Gallon - ", self.mpg)
    print("Current market price - ", self.price)

def fastest_car(self):
  ### NEED HELP HERE


honda_typer = Cars("Honda Civic Type R", 150, 5, 25.5, 32000)
merc_c = Cars("Mercedes C Class", 173, 5, 45, 90000)
bmw_M5 = Cars("MBW M5", 175, 4, 32, 50000)
```

What i would like to do is compare the self.speed of all 3 cars and print the maximum value with the name of the car. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fastest = max(honda_typer, merc_c, bmw_M5, key=lambda i: i.speed)`

Comment: It's not necessarily a mark of pride to *not* read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Answer (score 1):

If you add your `Cars` to a `list` you can use `max` with a custom sort function

```
cars = [honda_typer, merc_c, bmw_M5]
max(cars, key=lambda i: i.speed)
```

As a side note, your design is a bit odd. I would simply rename your class `Car` since it really represents just a single car. The aggregation of cars would simply be a list, it wouldn't make sense to have `Car.fastest_car` as a single car doesn't (and shouldn't) know about the other `Car` instances, instead it should just track its own attributes.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I will tweak my code with your suggestions also